# how to call a java method using jdbc in sql server 2008 using a trigger event (insert/update)?

Tags: java, sql-server, triggers

as the questions says I want to call a java method/function when a register in the SQL Server 2008 is inserted or updated so i can process the info through java. Is there a way to do this?? For the moment I'm polling the database every 5 seconds for changes in bit fields (false to true), but I'm having problems with excessive memory usage due to queries. Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to do this??

I think that the answer is No.

JDBC doesn't provide any way to do callbacks from the database into the JDBC client, so the only option would be to run the Java in the database server.  I don't think you can do that with SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. Triggers are built into the database server and can't call to external code unless the database supports that. Not suprisingly SQL Server doesn't have that kind of integration with Java.

PL/SQL and Java on the other hand would work.

Comment: Thanks anyway, i guess i'll stick with polling the database